# Identification of a feudal era / demon protagonist manga

Tags: shinobi-no-kuni

I'm gonna put in items what I remember

- The manga is on the feudal era
- The protagonist is part of a demon society, they constantly fight with the humans
- The leader of this society is a giant frog, or something similar
- The protagonist kidnaps a princess (or just a regular girl, don't remember)
- The protagonist is respected by others, since he's one of the most powerful demons, if not the most
- The protagonist respects the woman he kidnapped
- In the final chapter, she die trying to protect him after the war stopped
- I'm not sure but I think either the protagonist or the woman he kidnapped is named Momo, or simplified to Momo

May be really vague, but I can't remember anything more.
If I'm not mistaken, it's already finished.

Comment: in the second point by girl are you talking about the princess/girl the protagonist kidnaps?

Comment: the princess/girl is the same person, I just don't remember correctly if she was a princess or just a regular woman. And yes, it's the person he kidnapped.

Comment: no i was trying to confirm if the girl mentioned in the second point is the same as the princess/girl you mention gets kidnapped by the protagonist. if so the second point can be moved near to the bottom and reworded as something like *"I'm not sure but i think either the protagonist or the woman he kidnapped is named Momo or simplified to Momo"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it: **Shinobi no Kuni**

> **Synopsis (MyAnimeLIst)**
>
> Based on a novel by Wada Ryou, "Shinobi no kuni" brings a story that blends history and fiction as it shows the struggles happening during the 16th century in Iga, a region famous by the Iga Shinobi, the ninjas from Iga.

The protagonist name is actually Mumon, not Momo as I said. Would be hard to find it with a wrong name.

Comment: If you feel that this is the anime you were looking for, you may answer your own question, and accept this by clicking on the check mark beside the post.